# Timestamps in iChat

Tags: ichat

Is there a way to display a timestamp for each chat message in iChat?

(I'm aware that you can hover your mouse to see a timestamp tooltip, but I want to be able to copy/paste it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can enable them for every message in iChat. If you'd like that kind of functionality you might want to use an alternative chat client like [adium](http://adium.im/)